# Как сделать замену нескольких столбцов одного DF на значения столбцов другого DF

Tags: python, pandas

У меня есть два датафрейма:

`df_1`:

```
 FullName Портфель   Должность    Отдел
    A       ab       директор     риски
    B       cd       аналитик   оптимизация
    D       cd       аналитик   оптимизация
    C       ef       уборщик     персонал
    A       dg       директор     риски
    A       pr       директор     риски
```

`df_2`:

```
FullName  Должность       Отдел
    A  старший директор  финансы
    B     Nan           оптимизация
    D     Nan           оптимизация
```

Мне нужно, чтобы столбцы из `df_1` по соответствующему имени заменились на аналогичные столбцы из `df_2`, т.е.в результате должен получиться обновленный `df_1`:

```
 FullName Портфель   Должность             Отдел
    A       ab    старший директор        финансы
    B       cd         Nan              оптимизация
    D       cd         Nan              оптимизация
    C       ef       уборщик              персонал
    A       dg    старший директор        финансы
    A       pr    старший директор        финансы
```

Есть идеи, как это можно реализовать?

Была мысль сделать цикл по `set(df_2['FullName'])` и в нем находить через `.loc` нужный срез из `df_1` и заменять его на нужный срез из `df_2`, но не сработало.

Answer (score 0):

```
df_1.merge(df_2, how="right").append(df_1.iloc[len(df_2):])
```

---

*Объяснение:*

Сначала добавим в `df_2` отсутствующие столбцы

```
>>> df_1.merge(df_2, how="right")
```

> ```
>   FullName Портфель         Должность        Отдел
> 0        A      NaN  старший директор      финансы
> 1        B      NaN               Nan  оптимизация
> 2        D      NaN               Nan  оптимизация
> ```

и затем к полученной таблице добавим оставшиеся строки из `df_1`.

Comment: А есть ли возможность реализовать это, используя определенную выборку столбцов из датафреймов?

Comment: @Darina, лучше всего будет задать новый вопрос, со всеми нужными деталями и примерами. В комментариях не хватает места.